# Best method to use Bootstrap in Laravel 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I am using now Laravel 4,
What is the best method to use bootstrap for my site?
Is there some stuff I need to change and where do I put the css files?

Someone said that I need to use the `composer` and another said that I need to use the `artisan`

Thanks

Comment: you could use it either way, but you could also place the bootstrap files in your public folder and use them as you would do with any css/javascript files

Comment: Okay thank you!, so I need to make a new folder and put the file in there: `laravel/public/css/bootsrap.css`, is the stylesheet now automated loaded?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Some things you must know about Laravel:

**It has directly nothing to do with your front end, including Twitter Bootstrap.**

**Where you put your files is entirely up to you, but the public folder is (usually) where your public viewable files must go.**

CSS and JavaScript files are directly downloaded by browser, so those files should be in your public folder.

To download/use Bootstrap you have some options:

1) **Go to http://getbootstrap.com/ and download it.**

2) **Use bower (https://github.com/bower/bower) to download it for you.**

3) **If you are planning using a Bootstrap template, usually those already come with Bootstrap.**

4) Use a CDN, like http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

I, personally, use bower, those are the steps you can follow to install and use it:

**Install it**

```
[sudo] npm install bower
```

**Create a `.bowerrc` file in your project dir, which tells bower where to download your packages:**

```
{
    "directory": "public/bower"
}
```

**Create a `bower.json` file, which holds your installed packages:**

```
{
  "name": "YourApp.com",
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

Then you just need to install your packages using it:

```
bower install bootstrap -S
bower install jquery -S
```

And you can also use it to find packages

```
bower search google-code-prettify
```

After installing bootstrap, your css files would be located at:

```
public/bower/bootstrap/dist/css/
```

In Laravel there are many ways of including your assets, this is one of those, using Blade as you view compiler:

```
<link href="{{ asset('bower/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Can I instead just use the CDN and pull in the bootstrap file?

Answer (score 11):

#### Here's the approach if you don't want to use bower.

- Download bootstrap and extract the contents inside `public/components/`
- Using Blade as your view compiler, use it like this:

---

```
<link href="{{ asset('components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

or like this

```
{{ HTML::style('components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just include it on your app with composer:

> composer require twbs/bootstrap