# Best way to integrate twitter bootstrap in laravel

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5.3

What is the best way to integrate twitter bootstrap in laravel among these and why?
1. Using bootstrap CDN
2. Using precompiled bootstrap files
3. Using bootstrap source code (Less)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919486/best-method-to-use-bootstrap-in-laravel-4

Comment: "The best way" depends on many factors and one method may suite one's needs, but not the other's. So far my only choice is to use [Laravel Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir). Also, I'm mostly `bootstrap-sass` instead of it's _less_ version.